# I am getting this error in Flutter development

Tags: flutter

Invalid depfile: C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\ILearn.dart_tool\flutter_build\1be538b6cdd5bbbbffa6e09d3e915866\kernel_snapshot.d

Comment: Can you please explain briefly about your error?

Comment: Delete the file. if that doesn't fix it, re-install flutter.